# Mantra-Can anyone recommend me a mantra of devi or the adi-para shakti or the feminine aspect of God?

Tags: mantras, saraswati, durga

I want to chant the most true and the best mantra of devi---Maa Kali ,Maa durga,Maa Saraswati?
I do not know whether their is any generalized mantra for the feminine aspect of god?
Can anyone recommend from experience?

Comment: matra should only be taken from guru who has mantra siddhi! one should not chant these as they like! beware of sabdha-dosha! reciting mantras that are read/told by someone else gives very less or sometimes no benefit!

Comment: any mantra chanted with belief yields much benefit than celebrated mantras. All mantras are equally powerful, all names are gods names!

Comment: the only possible way is navarna mantra which gives the credit of worshipping all 3 mahashakti's, also this mantra _yaa devi sarvabhuteshu vishnumayeti shabdita namhastasye namhastasye namhastasye namo namah_.

Comment: @Creator The "yaa devi..." mantra is the one I included in my answer.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - You mentioned the whole stuti from Saptashati but I derived it's saar mantra and mentioned it. I also gave the narvan Mantra, this is not answer,its just a suggestion. This is saar mantra because its aaradhya is  the Vihnumaya ,Adimaya,or YogMaya the eternal shakti of Bramha(one God) without any divisions or specifications all others are just different manifestations of her.

Comment: "na mAtu daivatam param" There is no god superior to one's own mother. Rever your own mother as the adi parasakti. Additionally, you can pick up any devi stotra and chant it with devotion every day. All forms of the goddess embody all her shakti. But please make sure it is only a stotra. Mantras are to be given by a guru only. If you want a mantra, approach a guru who has done devi sadhana and they will guide you.

Comment: I would nominate 'soundarya lahiri', a composition written by Adi Shankara. But since the question is locked, here's the link to it. http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/saundaryalahari.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the most famous general Devi mantra is the Aparajita Stuti, AKA the Tantrik Devi Sukta, a mantra taken from the Devi Mahatmya (AKA Saptashati) of the Markandeya Purana, where the gods use this mantra to propitiate Durga.  [Here](https://www.satyananda.net/download/tantroktam-devi-sooktam.pdf) is the Sanskrit:

> नमो देव्यै महादेव्यै शिवायै सततं नमः। 
>   नमः प्रकृत्यै भद्रायै नियताः प्रणताः स्म ताम्॥९॥ 
>  
>   Namo devyai mahaa-devyai shivaayai satatam namaha | Namah prakåityai
>   bhadraayai niyataah praëataah sma taam ||
>
> रौद्रायै नमो नित्यायै गौर्ये धात्र्यै नमो नमः। 
>  
>   ज्योत्स्नायै चेन्दुरूपिण्यै सुखायै सततं नमः॥१०॥ 
>  
>   Raudraayai namo nityaayai gauryai dhaatrayai namo namaha | Jyotsnaayai
>   chendu-roopiëyai sukhaayai satatam namaha ||
>
> कल्याण्यै प्रणतां वृद्ध्यै सिद्ध्यै कुर्मो नमो नमः। 
>   नैर्ऋत्यै भूभृतां लक्ष्म्यै शर्वाण्यै ते नमो नमः॥११॥ 
>  
>   Kalyaaëyai praëataam våiddhyai siddhyai kurmo namo namaha |
>   Nair-åityai bhoo-bhåitaam lakshmyai sharvaaëyai te namo namaha ||
>
> दुर्गायै दुर्गपारायै सारायै सर्वकारिण्यै। 
>   ख्यात्यै तथैव कृष्णायै धूम्रायै सततं नमः॥१२॥ 
>  
>   Durgaayai durga-paaraayai saaraayai sarvakaarinyai | Khyaatyai tathaiva kåiñhëaayai
>   dhoomraayai satatam namaha ||
>
> अतिसौम्यातिरौद्रायै नतास्तस्यै नमो नमः। 
>   नमो जगत्प्रतिष्ठायै देव्यै कृत्यै नमो नमः॥१३॥ 
>  
>    Ati-saumyaati-raudraayai nataastasyai namo namaha | Namo
>   jagat-pratiñh-öhaayai devyai kåityai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु विष्णुमायेति शब्दिता। 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥१४॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥१५॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥१६॥ 
>  
>   Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu viñhëu-maayeti shabditaa | Namastasyai
>   namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु चेतनेत्यभिधीयते। 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥१७॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥१८॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥१९॥ 
>  
>   Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu cheta-netyabhi-dheeyate | Namastasyai
>   namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु बुद्धिरूपेण संस्थिता। 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥२०॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥२१॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥२२॥ 
>  
>   Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu buddhi roopeëa samsthitaa | Namastasyai
>   namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु निद्रारूपेण संस्थिता। 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥२३॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥२४॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥२५॥ 
>  
>   Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu nidraa roopeëa samsthitaa | Namastasyai
>   namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु क्षुधारूपेण संस्थिता। 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥२६॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥२७॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥२८॥ 
>  
>   Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu kshudhaa roopeëa samsthitaa | Namastasyai
>   namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषुच्छायारूपेण संस्थिता॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥२९॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥३०॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥३१॥ 
>  
>   Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu chhaayaa roopeëa samsthitaa | Namastasyai
>   namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु शक्तिरूपेण संस्थिता॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥३२॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥३३॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥३४॥ 
>  
>    Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu shakti roopeëa samsthitaa | Namastasyai
>   namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु तृष्णारूपेण संस्थिता॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥३५॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥३६॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥३७॥ 
>  
>   Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu tåiñhëaa roopeëa samsthitaa |
>   Namastasyai namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||
>
> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु क्षान्तिरूपेण संस्थिता॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥३८॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै॥३९॥ 
>   नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥४०॥ 
>  
>   Yaa devee sarvabhooteñhu kshaanti roopeëa samsthitaa | Namastasyai
>   namastasyai namastasyai namo namaha ||

And here is the English:

> We bow to the goddess, to the great goddess, to the energy of infinite
>   goodness.
>
> We prostrate, with hands together, to nature, to the excellent one.
>
> We bow to the reliever of sufferings, to the eternal, to the
>   embodiment of rays of light.
>
> We continually bow to the goddess who manifests light, to the form of
>   devotion, and happiness.
>
> We bow to the welfare of those who bow.
>
> To change, to perfection, to dissolution, to the wealth which sustains
>   earth, to the wife of consciousness, we bow.
>
> We bow to the one who removes difficulties, who removes beyond all
>   difficulties, to the essence.
>
> We bow to the extremely beautiful and to the extremely fierce, the
>   establisher of the perceivable world and who is the mundane existence,
>   the divine goddess in all existence who is addressed as the
>   perceivable form of the consciousness which pervades all.
>
> We bow to the divine goddess in all existence who resides all
>   throughout the consciousness and is known by the reflections of mind,
>   who resides in the forms of intelligence, sleep, hunger, appearance,
>   energy, desire, patient forgiveness, the form of all living beings.
>
> We bow to the divine goddess in all existence who resides in the forms
>   of humility, peace, and faith.
>
> We bow to the divine goddess in all existence who resides in the form
>   of beauty enhanced by love, and in the forms of true wealth, change
>   and recollection or memory.
>
> We bow to the divine goddess in all existence who resides in the forms
>   of compassion, satisfaction and Mother, and also confusion.
>
> Presiding over the senses of all beings and pervading all existence,
>   to the omnipresent goddess who individualizes creation we bow, we bow.
>
> In the form of consciousness she distinguishes the individual
>   phenomena of the perceivable universe. We bow, we bow, we bow, we bow
>   to her.

Comment: These are not to chanted without initiation.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I think only Vedic mantras require diksha, not Puranic mantras.  The Puranas are meant to be heard and chanted by all, without any process of initiation.

Comment: There are certain puranic mantras also esp in the chandi sapta sati that need to be given by a guru. The same is believed to be true of sundara kanda parayana too. Only a couple of chapters of devi mahatmyam can be read without initiation.

Comment: @moonstar2001 My understanding had always been that the Itihasas and Puranas can be recited in their entirety by anyone without initiation.  Do you know of some scripture that says certain portions can only be recited if you've been initiated?